# Доступ к невидимым элементам listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Всем привет. Листвью хранит только видимых детей. При прокрутке, дети которые уходят из зоны видимости-уничтожаются. Тем не менее, какой то способ должен быть. У меня lv из 100 элементов, нужно изменять все, в том числе и не видимые. На stackoverflow говорят, что все изменения элементов в таком случае должны происходить через адаптер, либо создать arraylist элементов листвью и с ними работать. Есть решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Зачем вам изменять вьюхи, если вам нужно изменить данные которые эти вьюхи отображают! Если вы используете `ArrayАdapter` или `SimpleAdapter`, нужно изменить массив элементов который вы ему даете и вызвать у адаптера `notifyDataSetChanged()` Когда листвью подгрузит уничтоженные элементы, в них подгрузит обновленные данные.

Comment: @katso Пожалуйста, опубликуйте комментарий ответом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ katso

---

Зачем вам изменять вьюхи, если вам нужно изменить данные которые эти вьюхи отображают! Если вы используете `ArrayАdapter` или `SimpleAdapter`, нужно изменить массив элементов который вы ему даете и вызвать у адаптера `notifyDataSetChanged()` Когда листвью подгрузит уничтоженные элементы, в них подгрузит обновленные данные.